# Simplify polyline with the intersection point kept

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, line, simplify

I have a some line and polygon features which consist of too many points, so I tried to simplify them.

I found the "[Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)".

I think it will work well for a single feature (line or polygon), but in my case, the feature are connected with others like this:

[image]

Note the point inside the red circle is the intersection point of the two line. This point must not be removed during the simplify process.

So I wonder if there is any out of box solution?

BTW, we have ArcMap Desktop 10. But we prefer to make it by program rather than manually since there are almost 20+ layers.

Comment: If you are looking for a detailed answer, please mention which software you are working on.

Comment: I update it. :)

Comment: try mapshaper.org

Answer (score 2):

The more straightforward workaround consists in splitting your lines at the intersections before running the simplify tools. The DP algorithm does not move end points.

After the simplification, you can use a dissolve tool in order to recover your original line network.

EDIT: With ArcGIS, the most simple method is to use "feature to line" if you have ArcInfo licence.

Comment: For splitting the line, I know how to split it for a single line, but I am not sure if it is possible to split features automatically in the whole layer.

Comment: If you run [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000) with output type points, you can then use [Split Line At Point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003w000000) to split all lines at all intersections.